# What is the Exact difference between Object Based and Object Oriented Languages

Tags: javascript, java, oop

Please explain this would be great if you can mention examples. I am really confused.

Also is the statement "Object based languages does not supports built-in objects" True ? can they be distinguished by built in objects ??